# Understanding this hypersurface definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry

> A set $M\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is called a 'hypersurface' of class
>   $C^k$ when it's locally the graph (plot?) of a function of $n$
>   variables of class $C^k$. It means that each point $p\in M$ belongs to
>   an open $V\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $V\cap M$ is the graph
>   (plot?) of a function of class $C^k$ defined on an open of the space
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$. When $n=1$, we say "curve", when $n=2$ we say
>   "surface"

I'm trying to understand this definition. Obviously it's trying to generalize the concept of surfaces to higher dimensions, and considering the case of dimension $1$ as being a curve. However I did not get what is $V\cap M$ and I'd love to see examples to get it better.

Comment: "Exercise": Carefully sketch the unit circle $M$ in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$, the solution set of the equation $x^{2} + y^{2} - 1 = 0$. Show that $M$ is not the graph of a real-valued function, but that $M$ satisfies the condition in your post. You'll need cases to handle all points $p = (x_{0}, y_{0})$. Suggestion: Use the four cases $y_{0} > 0$, $y_{0} < 0$, $x_{0} > 0$, and $x_{0} < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when they say "graph" they mean something very precise. Let $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ be a function of $n$ variables. Then its graph is the set
$$
\text{graph}(f):=\{x\in \mathbb R^n\colon (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,f(x)\},\qquad x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n).
$$
Here is what local means. For every point $p\in M$, there is an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ containing $p$ such that $M\cap U=\text{graph}(f)\cap U$ for some function $f\in C^k$. Note that both $f$ and $U$ are allowed to depend on $p$.

To visualize this, start by ignoring the word "local" and the intersections with open sets. Then $M$ is simply the graph of a function of $n$ variables. For $n=2$ think of the surface as a hill, where $f(x_1,x_2)$ is the height of a hill "above" the point $(x_1,x_2)$ on the $x_1x_2$-plane.

In three dimensions, think of $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ as the temperature of a point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in space. The temperature varies continuously from point to point. This is your hypersurface in a four-dimensional space.

For higher dimensions the "hill" analogy is strained, but you can still somehow think of $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ as coordinates giving the "address" of a point, and then $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is the label of that point. So there are $n$ degrees of freedom, and then your last coordinate $x_{n+1}=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is forced. In particular, a hypersurface is of dimension $n$.

Once this is clear, we can move on to locality. This means that, even though there might not be a single, globally defined, function that describes your hypersurface, you can cover it by pieces of functions. Think, for example when $n=1$, of a circle. We need different functions to describe the positive and negative semicircles, for example $f(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$. So it is the union of the graphs of several functions. Similarly, think of covering a sphere with hemispheres, each of which is given locally by a function of the form $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x_1^2-x_2^2}$.